# temporary use of release candidate python version in tox

Tags: python-2.7, tox, tox-globinterpreter

I am using `tox` to test my python packages. Now that python 2.7.13 has a release candidate, how do I test against this version using `tox` without immediately replacing my current python 2.7 version for normal use?

I know how to specify a path for python when creating a `virtualenv` and then I can install and run `py.test`. Tox builds its own virtualenv and I don't know how to influence the python version installed beyond selecting `py27`, `py26`, `py35`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can influence this using the PATH, by extending your PATH before calling tox (at least on Linux, probably not on Windows).

To get some more fine grained control and to get that to work on Windows (where AFAIK you cannot set an environment variable for a single command usage like on Unix/Linux), you can use the tox extension package `tox-globinterpreter` (disclaimer I am the author of that package) which you can install with `pip`.

The package adds a `--scan` option to `tox` which writes out an explicit mapping from `py27`, `py36`, etc to a python executable.

E.g. I do:

```
tox --scan /opt/python/{2,3}.?/bin/python  /opt/python/pypy2/bin/pypy
```

on my Linux based system, where /opt/python/X.Y is a link to the latest **released** Python version as installed in /opt/python/X.Y.Z (or the latest version in case of development version like 3.6), this gives as output:

```
interpreters:
python2.6 /opt/python/2.6/bin/python
python2.7 /opt/python/2.7/bin/python
python3.2 /opt/python/3.2/bin/python
python3.3 /opt/python/3.3/bin/python
python3.4 /opt/python/3.4/bin/python
python3.5 /opt/python/3.5/bin/python
python3.6 /opt/python/3.6/bin/python
pypy /opt/python/pypy2/bin/pypy
```

When I change the scan to:

```
tox --scan /opt/python/2.6/bin/python /opt/python/2.7.13*/bin/python \
    /opt/python/3.?/bin/python /opt/python/pypy2/bin/pypy
```

I get:

```
interpreters:
python2.6 /opt/python/2.6/bin/python
python2.7 /opt/python/2.7.13rc1/bin/python
python3.2 /opt/python/3.2/bin/python
python3.3 /opt/python/3.3/bin/python
python3.4 /opt/python/3.4/bin/python
python3.5 /opt/python/3.5/bin/python
python3.6 /opt/python/3.6/bin/python
pypy /opt/python/pypy2/bin/pypy
```

And `tox -e py27` will be using the 2.7.13 release candidate. You can save the configuration file (in `~/.config/tox` or `%APPDATA%\tox`) if switching back and forth, but rerunning the scan is pretty fast, so I would make a shell script/alias/batch file for that.